# apt update problem - 404

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt, update

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3B running Jessie. "Sudo apt update" is throwing many 404 errors. Here's an example:

```
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
```

My sources.list file is:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Hasn't jessie reached end of life?

```
Index of /raspbian/dists/
../
bookworm/                                          26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
bookworm-staging/                                  26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
bullseye/                                          26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
bullseye-staging/                                  26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
buster/                                            26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
buster-staging/                                    26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
oldoldstable/                                      26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
oldstable/                                         26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
stable/                                            26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
stretch/                                           26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
stretch-staging/                                   26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
testing/                                           26-Aug-2021 18:30                   -
```

> Debian “jessie” Release Information Debian 8.11 was released June
> 23rd, 2018. Debian 8.0 was initially released on April 26th, 2015. The
> release included many major changes, described in our press release
> and the Release Notes.
>
> Debian 8 has been superseded by Debian 9 (stretch). Regular security
> support updates have been discontinued as of June 17th, 2018.
>
> Jessie also benefits from Long Term Support (LTS) until the end of
> June 2020. The LTS is limited to i386, amd64, armel and armhf. For
> more information, please refer to the LTS section of the Debian Wiki.

Comment: Debian Jessie is EOL but I could not find an official statement about raspbian jessie, but it  no longer appears on the raspberry pi mirrors.

Comment: It has been removed from the Raspbian servers (see above) which is fairly clear as a statement.

Comment: Keep in mind that Raspbian/RpiOS *is* Debian for the most part.  There are some tweaks, configuration changes, etc., but once the Debian base is over, there's no way for something closely derived from it to keep on truckin without creating a distro from the ground-up (which is probably a bad idea/not desirable).  Regular users new to linux may not perceive this relationship, but that is the back-story.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Volumio Package Server by replacing

```
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with

`http://archive.volumio.org`

Comment: @MatsK I disagree. This is the only answer here that actually gives instructions to fix it; the others just imply there's no solution other than a full upgrade/reinstall. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, Jessie is dead. Though, you can still access the old packages by updating "**/etc/apt/sources.list**" and adding:

```
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib
```

as per [this forum thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?f=66&t=237469).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it.

Jessie is dead! It is doubly obsolete (soon to be triple).

There will NEVER be any updates from the Foundation.

If you are happy running it just leave it as is (just as I do with my Windows XP).

Comment: I so badly want to downvote this because you're running XP - then I remembered one of our work machines is running Vista

Comment: @Bravo I am not actually running XP. I refused Vista, Win7 would have cost me more than a new computer (to upgrade all my compilers etc) so I bought a Mac. I very occasionally turn on to run my genealogy program (which uses Windows proprietary databases). My point was that if you want to use an obsolete OS (and it does what you want) **don't fiddle with it**